# Control shrink priority in CSS

Tags: html, css

Let's say I have a page with centered content. This content ideally will be centered, with big margins (or paddings, I'm really a newbie at this) on each side.

How do I control the priority, i.e. which elements shrink first, when the window is resized?

Check the following example.

https://jsfiddle.net/v7412jpg/

It all shrinks proportionally (horizontally), which I do not want. The margins should be sacrificed before we start touching the content.

I have also tried with the `flex-shrink` concept, without success:

https://jsfiddle.net/w0s4xmc0/1148/

Comment: i guess it's somehow easy ... you make your content width:100% and you add a max-width to it ... and the space around will shrink first then the content

Comment: Your first fiddle has no width :D

Comment: sorry, fixed the typo

Comment: Why not do something along the lines of `width: 1200px; max-width: 70%;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set a width and a max-width for your body. For example:

```
.content {
  width: 95%; /* the remaining 5% is your "padding" */
  max-width: 600px; 
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
```